# How to separate each column in a data frame and make each column into its own new data set

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

The title of this question may have been a bit confusing, so let me give a bit more detail. I apologize in advance if there are flaws in my terminology. So here is an example of my data frame

```
a b c d e
1 4 2 7 8
2 4 3 7 1
4 3 5 9 3
```

So what I would like to do is make each column it's own dataset. I know you can do something like `a <- df[c(1)] b <- df[c(2)]` etc.. My real data frame has thousands of columns, so having to type that out is going to get annoying. I was wonder if there is a quicker way to do this? Ideally, I would like the new data sets to have the same name as the column, and I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that. I know there will be thousands of data sets but I have a computer that can handle it

Comment: Is there a reason to have all those data frames loose in the environment, as opposed to each being an item in a list? With this toy example, it would mean you have one object, e.g. `df_list`, and call `df_list$b` or `df_list[[2]]`, instead of having 5 different objects with nothing holding them together. It might be preference, but something to think about

Comment: @camille that is actually a great point, I didn't think about that. This is actually a much better way of doing this.

Comment: Cool, do you need help doing that, or do you think you have it from here?

Comment: @camille I do, but I will ask it in another question. I am going to use these columns to filter a massive data frame. For that I will actually need to make new dataframe for each set of filtering. I need to figure out how to kind of automate a way of doing that instead of typing out some dplyr command 2000 times.

Comment: `purrr`'s `map` functions should help you avoid repeated `dplyr` commands

Comment: you might be interested in `with` and `within` also, try `with(head(iris), Sepal.Length +2)` or `within(head(iris), Sepal.Length +2)` .

Comment: @camille I will check it out! I really really appreciate the suggestions! They were super helpful. I know they seem minor to you but I am so new to this! Every little bit helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list2env`, but think twice, probably you're better off keeping things as structured as possible:

```
df <- head(iris)
list2env(df,envir = .GlobalEnv)
Species
# [1] setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa
# Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Or to keep them as one column data.frames:

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(names(df), function(x) df[x]),names(df)),
  envir = .GlobalEnv)
Species
#   Species
# 1  setosa
# 2  setosa
# 3  setosa
# 4  setosa
# 5  setosa
# 6  setosa
```